chrome api to list current audio stream
In chrome and its variants (chromium, brave, edge, etc) there is a little panel that shows the currently playing audio - does anyone know how to access this information in an extension or similar? Would be very useful.
I've looked at lots of source code for extensions, but they seem predicated on using a certain player/site. Chrome seems to be able to parse information from nearly all sites, etc. This makes me think there's an HTML5 api/interface that is being used, which is great. It would just be nice to be able to access the output from chrome.

use navigator.mediaSession property to access the current media playback..
